# Can Spring Batch use the results of Driving Query more than once?

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have a batch process that I need to implement. My clients preferred batch framework is Spring Batch.

The logical process is

1. select a load of records from a database at a known state
2. write the records to a file
3. update the state of the records that have been written to the file

The process is likely to touch quite a large number of records, and I'd like to keep the updating transaction as short as possible, so my intended design is to

1. use the Driving Query Pattern to produce a list of candidate rows
2. iterate over the results from step 1 writing them to an output file
3. Begin transaction
4. iterate over the results of step 1 again, updating the state of the rows in the database
5. End Transaction

I'm intending to use an existing data access layer to do the database work, rather than using the spring JdbcCursorItemReader.

Is this something that Spring Batch can cope with readily, or do I need to think again?

Thanks in advance

Dave

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is described in [Common Batch Patterns](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/patterns.html) document; you may read section **11.4 Driving Query Based ItemReaders**

By using a [CompositeItemWriter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/CompositeItemWriter.html) having a file output writer and your db update logic and a processor that takes input from your first step, you may simulate the behaviour wanted.

Hope that this helps

Comment: I looked at CompositeItemWriter, but I got the feeling that for each item that was passed to it it would, for example, write item to file followed by write item to database. What I want to do is write item to file for ALL items found by my driving query, and when that has completed, wrote ALL items to database. Am I misreading the documentation for CompositeItemWriter ?